# Want to remove 2nd disk but MBR needs to be moved. How do I do it?

Tags: mbr

I have a laptop with two HD, the second one was added later. I had Windows Server 2008 installed on the first disk (0) and thn added the second disk (1).
Next I installed Windows 7 on the second disk (1) and later removed Windows Server 2008.
The original Windows Server 2008 partition is largely empty but I cannot re-format it because the orginal Windows Server 2008 folders are still there.

I want to take the second disk out and use it elsewhere.

I cloned the current c: (disk 1) to a vhd on the old partition (disk 0) but when I boot to it the boot fails.

While I could install Windows 7 directly into the vhd on (0) I really want to simply use the vhd clone having added the vhd in bcdedit the boot menu appears.

But When I try taking the second disk out the boot fails. A colleague suggests running sysprep on the vhd but I cannot boot it. If I take the second disk (1) out of the machine then I cannot get to the boot menu.

Therefore it seems to me that I need to move the mbr but (blush) I don't know how to do this and I cannot risk losing any contents on the second disk (1).

What should I do please?o

Answer (score 0):

Ok. try this:

Start -> Type "cmd" -> type:

```
  fixboot
  fixmbr
  bcdboot X:\windows (where "X" is your bootable disk" C:)
```

If doesn't work, try it from the Recovery Console on Windows DVD.

Feedbacks.